# List with Association Count in Different Time Ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postgres version 11.x, and I'm trying to bring a list of Companies (central entity) with some association counts (from 2 different tables, but I can adapt from examples).

```
companies 1-n table_a (huge table, indexed, with created_at)
companies 1-n table_b (huge table, indexed, with created_at)
```

What I'm trying to build is

```
company_id, table_a_total_count, table_a_last_14_days_count, table_a_last_30_days_count, table_b_total_count...
1, 1000, 50, 100, 200, 50...
2, 1000, 50, 100, 200, 50
...
```

```sql
SELECT c.id as company_id,
       c.name as company_name,
       c.created_at as company_created_at,
FROM companies c;
```

My question:

1. Should I use a subquery for each time range?
2. Should I build a `WITH` query and then create the time ranges on it?
3. What's the best way to do it thinking about the performance?

Don't need to code, just to give me the right direction. I'm thinking most about performance.

EDIT1:

I'm thinking about a query like

```sql
SELECT company_id,
       COUNT(*) as count_total,
       COUNT(*) FILTER ( WHERE created_at > current_date - interval '14 days' ) as count_last_14_days,
       COUNT(*) FILTER ( WHERE created_at > current_date - interval '30 days' ) as count_last_30_days
FROM leads
GROUP BY company_id;
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the matching, expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 0):

My final solution was to use 2 JOINs from the following query

```sql
SELECT leads.company_id,
       COUNT(*) as count_total,
       COUNT(*) FILTER ( WHERE leads.created_at > current_date - interval '14 days' ) as count_last_14_days,
       COUNT(*) FILTER ( WHERE leads.created_at > current_date - interval '30 days' ) as count_last_30_days,
       COUNT(*) FILTER ( WHERE leads.created_at BETWEEN c.created_at AND c.created_at + interval '14 days' ) as count_initial_14_days,
       COUNT(*) FILTER ( WHERE leads.created_at BETWEEN c.created_at AND c.created_at + interval '30 days' ) as count_initial_30_days
FROM leads
INNER JOIN companies c on leads.company_id = c.id
GROUP BY leads.company_id;
```